# Converting a number to base-N string.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm not sure if the title is the correct description.
What I want to do is basically like this:
For example, if I have a binary sequence of 3-bits, I can have the following permutations:

1 -> [0,0,0]

2 -> [0,0,1]

3 -> [0,1,0]

4 -> [0,1,1]

5 -> [1,0,0]

6 -> [1,0,1]

7 -> [1,1,0]

8 -> [1,1,1]

But instead of binary sequence, I have a decimal array of integers upper bounded by some value N. Each of the digits can go from 0 to N.

So something like this:

1 -> [0,0,0]

2 -> [0,0,1]

3 -> [0,0,2]

...

i -> [0,0,N]

i+1 -> [0,1,0]

...

...

Is there a closed-form solution to find the digits of any n-th permutation?
Even a recursive solution? Or is iterative the only option?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Remember to LaTeX your question.

Comment: Thank you Culver. Sorry, first time posting. I will figure out how to LateX.

Comment: @RossMillikan These aren't permutations (even though madu calls them that). They are base-$(N+1)$ numbers.

Comment: @Arthur:  you are right.

Comment: @Arthur Thank you. Yes, permutations is a wrong a characterization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are really doing is converting a number to base $N+1$.  If your number is $k$, divide it by $N+1$ getting a quotient $q$ and remainder $r$.  The last character in your string is $r$.  Now continue by dividing $q$ by $N+1$.  The remainder is the next to last character and keep going with the quotient.  When the quotient becomes $0$ stop.